# Factorising a quadratic equation

Tags: factoring, quadratics

I've just started studying for an A-Level in Mathematics. This is probably a simple question but when I factorized the quadratic equation

$15x^2+42x-9$

I took out the common factor $3$ to get

$3(5x^2 + 14x - 3)$

Then factorized as follows:

$3(5x^2 - 1x + 15x - 1) = \\
3(x(5x -1) + 3(5x - 1)) = \\
3(x+3)(5x-1).$

When I checked the answer it was

$3(5x-1)(x+3)$

My question is this answer the same as the one I arrived to but with a different arrangement, or was my answer simply wrong?

This is my first question on math.stackexchange.com so I apologize in advance if I'm no adhering to the site's rules, e.g. what not to ask on the site.

Comment: Your answer is fine! Remember that the unknowns in the parentheses represent numbers, and we know that the order of multiplication does not matter. $2\times 3=3\times 2$ and so forth.

Comment: 3(x+3)(5x−1) = 3(5x−1)(x+3)

Comment: Wow, you got a 100 points without even asking a question. I asked 28 and only got 100. But to answer your question the arrangements doesn't matter. What you did was right!

Comment: @Q.matin Association Bonus because I have an account on stackoverflow.com where I have 2200+ points.

Comment: @Andrew since you answered first, do you think you could answer the question officially so I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: Found an error on line 7. You need to change 1 to a 3. The rules of this Web site don't let me edit your post because the edit would be less than 6 characters long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the answer is the same   if you work in a classical set of numbers
($\mathbb R$  for  example). (I suppose that since this concerne the A-level.)
In that sets wa have :  $a \times b = b \times a$   for all $a$  and $b$  in  it.
We say  that: ' Multiplication is commutative in these sets'.

Comment: I was going to wait for Andrew, but I guess you answered the question first, so I'll mark this as the answer to the question, thank you.

Comment: Thank you and good luck in your career in mathematics!